# Create a Matlab plugin for Sonarqube

Tags: matlab, plugins, sonarqube

I'm Setting up a new plugin for SonarQube that would analyze Matlab code. I read on this link about the procedure : https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/new-languages/  and I also read a lot of stuff, but I still don't really understand how to do the first step, the grammar part with SSLR. Could you guide me with that ?

I've tried to understand the SonarPython, but it is complex to modify it into what I'm looking for.